# What syntax is correct in order to extract texts between curly braces with newline?

Tags: python, regex

I am very new to regex and I need to extract some text between a pair of curly braces. I tried to do this on my own but I already spent too much time on it and it is not getting anywhere.

I modified code from another thread `<p>([\s\S]+?)</p>` into `{([\s\S]+?)}\n` but it is not what I want and I am stuck here.

Here is the text I need to work on.

```
{
    "timeStamp": 1,
    "src": [
        { "id": 0, "tag": "", "x": 0.000, "y": 0.000, "z": 0.000, "activity": 0.000 },
        { "id": 0, "tag": "", "x": 0.000, "y": 0.000, "z": 0.000, "activity": 0.000 },
        { "id": 0, "tag": "", "x": 0.000, "y": 0.000, "z": 0.000, "activity": 0.000 },
        { "id": 0, "tag": "", "x": 0.000, "y": 0.000, "z": 0.000, "activity": 0.000 }
    ]
}
{
    "timeStamp": 2,
    "src": [
        { "id": 0, "tag": "", "x": 0.000, "y": 0.000, "z": 0.000, "activity": 0.000 },
        { "id": 0, "tag": "", "x": 0.000, "y": 0.000, "z": 0.000, "activity": 0.000 },
        { "id": 0, "tag": "", "x": 0.000, "y": 0.000, "z": 0.000, "activity": 0.000 },
        { "id": 0, "tag": "", "x": 0.000, "y": 0.000, "z": 0.000, "activity": 0.000 }
    ]
}
```

I need to extract text between the curly braces at the beginning and the one at the end including curly braces themselves.

So a match example would be:

```
{
    "timeStamp": 1,
    "src": [
        { "id": 0, "tag": "", "x": 0.000, "y": 0.000, "z": 0.000, "activity": 0.000 },
        { "id": 0, "tag": "", "x": 0.000, "y": 0.000, "z": 0.000, "activity": 0.000 },
        { "id": 0, "tag": "", "x": 0.000, "y": 0.000, "z": 0.000, "activity": 0.000 },
        { "id": 0, "tag": "", "x": 0.000, "y": 0.000, "z": 0.000, "activity": 0.000 }
    ]
}
```

What syntax is correct for me to extract blocks like described above? I would appreciate it very much.

Comment: Regexes are not good at matching balanced text (e.g. where nested braces may be present). Having said that, in your case all you need is to match braces that are unindented: `(${.*?$})`

Comment: That all looks like valid JSON, just use `json.loads` to turn it into a dict.

Comment: @JaredSmith I have all of these data in a log file. I tried to use `json.load` but it gives me an extra data error since each big curly braces would represent a dictionary and json.load does not recognize multiple dicts. Anyway to tackle this problem?

Comment: @Cameron thank you, I will take a note of that. The syntax you provided is not working for me. It does not match the subject string

Comment: Oops, I forgot to escape the braces with backslashes

Comment: @Cameron so the correct form should be like this `($\{.*?$\})` ?

Comment: @yihan Yes, that's right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If border between data structures is always denoted by `}\n{` (`}` *newline* `{`) you might do:

```
import json
import re
text = '''
{
    "timeStamp": 1,
    "src": [
        { "id": 0, "tag": "", "x": 0.000, "y": 0.000, "z": 0.000, "activity": 0.000 },
        { "id": 0, "tag": "", "x": 0.000, "y": 0.000, "z": 0.000, "activity": 0.000 },
        { "id": 0, "tag": "", "x": 0.000, "y": 0.000, "z": 0.000, "activity": 0.000 },
        { "id": 0, "tag": "", "x": 0.000, "y": 0.000, "z": 0.000, "activity": 0.000 }
    ]
}
{
    "timeStamp": 2,
    "src": [
        { "id": 0, "tag": "", "x": 0.000, "y": 0.000, "z": 0.000, "activity": 0.000 },
        { "id": 0, "tag": "", "x": 0.000, "y": 0.000, "z": 0.000, "activity": 0.000 },
        { "id": 0, "tag": "", "x": 0.000, "y": 0.000, "z": 0.000, "activity": 0.000 },
        { "id": 0, "tag": "", "x": 0.000, "y": 0.000, "z": 0.000, "activity": 0.000 }
    ]
}
'''
data = re.split('(?<=})\n(?={)',text) # now data is list of 2 strs, which could be loaded using json module
first = json.loads(data[0]) # convert JSON str to dict
second = json.loads(data[1])
print('first:',first,'second:',second,sep='\n')
```

Output:

```
first:
{'timeStamp': 1, 'src': [{'id': 0, 'tag': '', 'x': 0.0, 'y': 0.0, 'z': 0.0, 'activity': 0.0}, {'id': 0, 'tag': '', 'x': 0.0, 'y': 0.0, 'z': 0.0, 'activity': 0.0}, {'id': 0, 'tag': '', 'x': 0.0, 'y': 0.0, 'z': 0.0, 'activity': 0.0}, {'id': 0, 'tag': '', 'x': 0.0, 'y': 0.0, 'z': 0.0, 'activity': 0.0}]}
second:
{'timeStamp': 2, 'src': [{'id': 0, 'tag': '', 'x': 0.0, 'y': 0.0, 'z': 0.0, 'activity': 0.0}, {'id': 0, 'tag': '', 'x': 0.0, 'y': 0.0, 'z': 0.0, 'activity': 0.0}, {'id': 0, 'tag': '', 'x': 0.0, 'y': 0.0, 'z': 0.0, 'activity': 0.0}, {'id': 0, 'tag': '', 'x': 0.0, 'y': 0.0, 'z': 0.0, 'activity': 0.0}]}
```

Explanation: In `re.split` first argument I used zero-length assertions, which allows me to ask `re.split` to split at `\n` which is between `}` and `{`, without loss of `}` or `{`.

Answer (score 0):

While playing with regular expressions I *highly encourage* you to check this out [regex101](https://regex101.com). This is a great website which allows you to test your regular expressions online and explains every step that is taken when expression is evaluated.

Answering your question, proper regex would be: `^{([\s\S]+?)^}`

You can see the explanation what is going on [here](https://regex101.com/r/jzicXf/3) in *EXPLANATION* box on the top right.

Although, it feels that regex is not the best fit to solve your problem as the text sample you provided seems to be *almost* valid JSON format, you may want to use  `json.loads` as mentioned in comments, after applying some minor changes to text (adding commas between `}\n{` and wrapping everything in `[ ... ]`).

Comment: the regex you provided does give me everything inside of the curly braces but it only returns 1 match. I think I will try using `json.loads`. Thank you!